# Regex grab name and value from a text that could be in a different languages

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to extract the spec name and spec value from a short product description that I have here:

> Brand name:  Lenovo‏,  Model:  IdeaPad 320‏,  Size:  15.6''‏,  CPU: 
>   Intel Core i3 - U‏, The Operating System:  Free Dos‏,  Capacity: 
>   500GB‏,  GPU:  Intel‏,  Memory Size:  4GB‏,  Resolution:  1366x768‏, 
>   Optical Drive:  DVD-RW (Dual Layer)‏,  Color:  Red‏,  Connection
>   Ports:  HDMI‏, USB 3.0‏, USB Type-C‏,  Features:  HDD 5400RPM‏, Intel
>   Skylake Processor‏, Full Keyboard‏, Bluetooth‏,  Warranty:  1 Year‏,

I'm not that good with regex. I'm still new to it but I have tried the following patterns. I have managed to detect the spec names only when I added another pattern for the value but it does not work for all spec values because of the different characters and possibilities. what I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Having the spec name and value selected in full match.
2. Have the first group of the full match to contain the spec name and the second group to contain the spec value.

This is the pattern I made, but only for English text

```
((^[a-zA-Z]+|\s[a-zA-Z]+))+:( +[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Also here is the text in a different language, Hebrew. The text is supposed to be read from right to left.

> יצרן:  Lenovo‏,  דגם:  IdeaPad 320‏,  גודל:  15.6''‏,  מעבד:  Intel Core i3 - U‏,  מערכת הפעלה:  ללא מערכת הפעלה‏,  נפח:  500GB‏,  כרטיס מסך:  Intel‏,  גודל זכרון:  4GB‏,  רזולוציה:  1366x768‏,  כונן אופטי:  (DVD-RW (Dual Layer‏,  צבע:  אדום‏,  חיבורים:  HDMI‏, USB 3.0‏, USB Type-C‏,  תכונות:  דיסק קשיח 5400Rpm‏, מעבד Skylake‏, מקלדת מלאה‏, Bluetooth‏,  משך אחריות:  שנה‏,

Comment: You are asking for a regex that detect a word in every language ? Not sure if it's possible. But you can write a regex per languages.

Comment: @vincrichaud ok it seems i didnt ask the question properly and im new to this and cant find where i can edit my question if thats even possible, any way for now forget about the Hebrew  my issue is with the regex that i made that it does not select the whole value it stops at any characters that are not English letters or numbers the pattern after the ":"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. I'm not sure about the Hebrew, but the English looks OK. Decomposing the spec text is based on the assumption that a "spec name" doesn't contain a comma and the spec value doesn't contain a colon. (It might be possible to overcome the latter.)

```
public class Product {

  static String prodEng = "Brand name: Lenovo‏, Model: IdeaPad 320‏, Size: 15.6\"‏, CPU: Intel Core i3 - U‏, The Operating System: Free Dos‏, Capacity: 500GB‏, GPU: Intel‏, Memory Size: 4GB‏, Resolution: 1366x768‏, Optical Drive: DVD-RW (Dual Layer), Color: Red‏, Connection Ports: HDMI‏, USB 3.0‏, USB Type-C‏, Features: HDD 5400RPM‏, Intel Skylake Processor‏, Full Keyboard‏, Bluetooth‏, Warranty: 1 Year‏,";

  static String prodHeb = "יצרן: Lenovo‏, דגם: IdeaPad 320‏, גודל: 15.6''‏, מעבד: Intel Core i3 - U‏, מערכת הפעלה: ללא מערכת הפעלה‏, נפח: 500GB‏, כרטיס מסך: Intel‏, גודל זכרון: 4GB‏, רזולוציה: 1366x768‏, כונן אופטי: (DVD-RW (Dual Layer‏, צבע: אדום‏, חיבורים: HDMI‏, USB 3.0‏, USB Type-C‏, תכונות: דיסק קשיח 5400Rpm‏, מעבד Skylake‏, מקלדת מלאה‏, Bluetooth‏, משך אחריות: שנה‏,";

  private String specStr;
  private Map<String,String> specMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  private Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "([^,]+?):\\s*([^:]+)?,\\s*" );

  public Product( String spec ){
    this.specStr = spec;
    decompose( this.specStr );
  }

  private void decompose( String s ){
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher( s );
    int pos = 0;
    while( mat.find( pos ) ){
      String key = mat.group( 1 );
      String val = mat.group( 2 );
      pos += mat.group( 0 ).length();
      specMap.put( key, val );
    }
  }

  public Map<String,String> getSpecs(){
    return specMap;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Product pe = new Product( prodEng );
    pe.getSpecs().forEach( (k, v) -> { System.out.println( k + ": " + v ); } );
    ph = new Product( prodHeb );
    ph.getSpecs().forEach( (k, v) -> { System.out.println( k + ": " + v ); } );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot your pattern worked perfectly with English and Hebrew :)

Comment: i was wondering why would you have the mat.find() start at a certain position instead of just having it to loop over the matches by it self ? whats the benefit , like is there a chance for the find() with no starting position miss a match and skip it or something ? and again thanks for your answer :)

Comment: A Java matcher doesn't loop by itself. Repeating a find requires either setting the starting point or a truncation of the string, both to avoid matching the same substring over and over again.

Comment: yes now i know having a true condition inside the while() function well keep looping forever (as long as the condition is true) but some how if you do this while(m.find()) with no starting position in the find () it will loop over matches in order with out looping over again on same match and the condition changes to false by it self when there is no more matches, i dont set it to false or anything that is why i asked you whats the difference. If you try this while(m.find()){System.out.println(mat.group( 1 )) } it does exactly as you did in your answer

Comment: Oh, I see. - I guess that I thought originally that keeping track of the position would be a good idea for reporting a mismatch, but I never needed that because it went smoothly on the first run. Throw it out if you don't need it.